# Youtube analytics api complete matrices and deminsions

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I want to get complete information about a channel analytics via youtube api v3
here a getting these things against that link

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={channel id} &key={api key}

it return me the following

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/yx2kycRgGr3IBhj8KFKCmbbflyM\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
 {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/1AsA31YnMnri_xHR1KqZOPlKHqA\"",
  "id": "UCBUfXmMdjyPCPxknz5f5VDg",
   "statistics": {
   "viewCount": "214772",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "4168",
   "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
   "videoCount": "38"
 }
}
]
}
```

But i want compete analytics against a channel like earning of channel view from upload date against a channel video gender of viewers ,total views mintues age target 
Can i get these whole youtube analytics via api v3

Comment: It looks like you're using the data api? If you want analytics, there's an actual [analytics api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/). Not sure if it has channel based data, but [demographics](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#demographic-reports) sounds like what you want. I suggest you thoroughly go over the api. If the data isn't listed there, then it probably can't be retrieved.